# Which partition to install Ubuntu in so as not to erase/make more bad things happen to Windows?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows-7

I'm trying to install Ubuntu alongside Windows, but not within Windows. I want to use Grub as the bootloader instead of the Windows MBR. I was installing off the liveDVD for 15.04, the amd64 version.

When confronted with the partitioning screen, I realized I didn't really know what to partition. My `/dev/sda2` partition is the biggest, at 734GB. But, that's labeled as Windows Recovery Environment.

[Here's my partioning screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lsLl.jpg)

Sorry for the crappy photo, but I don't know how to screenshot from this screen.

I also don't know which partition to put the bootloader on. The default is `/dev/sda`, but it also has options to do `/dev/sda`'s 1-4.

I also don't know what I need in terms of a swap partition. Isn't this where the bootloader should be? How big does this partition need to be?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The grub bootloader, if you want it as your loader for multiple OSes, goes on the first bootable drive, which would be `/dev/sda`, and not the partitions.  Even Windows installs its bootloader to the MBR of the drive.  That is also where `grub` would install to, but it will scan all your partitions for boot files.  So, your Windows would still boot correctly.

Looking at your pic there, I see the 15GB partition is actually your Windows Recovery partition, and your 736GB partition is that of your actual Windows installation.  If you are not planning on using that much space to Windows, I would recommend shrinking `/dev/sda2` down and installing Ubuntu into the new blank area.  But, as a safety precaucion of your data, first back up your data from Windows before you resize any partitions, as there is always the chance of something going wrong and messing up all your partitions.

Comment: I shrunk SDA2 to half the size, but the new free space is labeled unusable. As I understand it, I can only use 4 partitions of dev/sda. Can I delete the 33mb one?

Comment: @evamvid See if you can move sda3 into the blank area next to sda2,, then slide sda4 next to sda3, then it should work. I believe it is saying unusable due to the space between partitions.

Comment: I can't drag them around. I'm going to download Gparted and see if I can do it with that.

Comment: @evamvid good choice!  I love gparted for partition manipulation.

Comment: Ok, using gparted. Is it possible to "drag and drop" the partitions? I'm trying to move them using the free space before and after, but keep accidentally putting them on top of each other/getting it wrong, and having to start over.

Comment: also, it keeps telling me I'm moving the boot sector and could cause boot to fail. I think this shouldn't be a problem as I will be freshly installing the bootloader, but I'm not sure.

Comment: OK, I got them next to each other, but Ubuntu still has the space marked unusable, and I'm not sure what to delete/merge/rename.

Comment: @evamvid It looks like there are 4 primary partitions on your drive.  Under the MSDOS Partitioning scheme that Microsoft uses with Windows OSes, it only allows a maximum of 4 primary partitions.  They should have put the extras into an extended, which I am not seeing.  I am not sure what the 107MB partition is for.  It could be something for emergency Windows repair.  Did you create the startup discs for your system when you purchased it?  If you did, you could delete that partition, that would give you the primary partition needed to install Ubuntu.

Comment: No, I didn't, and I inherited the system.

Comment: @evamvid From what I can see, it looks as though the 107MB partition is used for diagnostics software.  As long as we don't destroy the 15GB Recovery partition, it should be fine.

Comment: So do I reformat the fat32 one as ntfs, expand it, and use that??

Comment: That one (the 107 mb one) has Bios update stuff in it from HP.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24277/discussion-between-terrance-and-evamvid).

Comment: @evamvid Moving this over to chat.  http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24277/discussion-between-terrance-and-evamvid